# How to change visibility on an html button before rendering the html it is in? Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I change an html button `<button style='display: none'>clear</button>` which is hidden, to be visible from inside a controller when a variable `$show` = `true`.

View

```
<button style='display: none'>clear</button>
```

Controller

```
$show = false
def print
  if $show
    #change visibility of button
  end
end
```

Comment: $show is a get variable or just another variable used in your code

Comment: just another variable on my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple like this?

```
<button style='display: <%= $show ? "inline" : "none">'>clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it is working

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" style="display:none;" id="btn" value="click me!"/>
  <?php 
    $show = '';
    if(isset($show))
    {?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").css("display","block");
        });

    </script>
    <?php } ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified in the title that this is rails

Comment: ok but you can still use jquery to change the css of the button.